# Java Ebean save list to database

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
public class Album extends Model {

    /**
     * Generated UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7954535168852819314L;


    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String name;


    public static Finder<Long, Album> find = new Finder<Long, Album>(Long.class, Album.class);
}
```

I need an `Album` to have a list of `Song`s. can I just add `public List<Song> songs`?

Is it a better practice to just have an entity Song then add a collection in the Album Entity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost... to make it working you need to add annotation with relation type, Many songs belongs to One Album add this field to the `Song` model:

```
@ManyToOne
public Album album;
```

So in your `Album` model you can add *reverse* field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "album")
public List<Song> songs;
```

Be careful about `mappedBy` - it need to have the same value as the field added to the `Song` model.